# Foundation web icons

Tags: css, zurb-foundation

I am trying to add an icon for facebook on my page using web icons by zurb. I followed this page : http://zurb.com/playground/social-webicons , downloaded the zip, created a folder named webicons in the root folder and pasted all icons in there. This is the line i used for test :

```
<a href="#" class="fc-webicon facebook">Like us on Facebook</a>
```

It displays just the text, but if i change the class to "webicon facebook" it displays a small box(icon shaped) shadowed.

Comment: http://guides.rubyonrails.org/asset_pipeline.html#coding-links-to-assets

Answer (score 0):

It looked like the css was not linked to class in my html file so i modified this way:

```
.webicon.facebook {
  background: url("webicons/webicon-facebook-m.png"); 
}
```

To:

```
.no-svg .webicon.facebook {
  background: url("webicons/webicon-facebook-m.png"); 
}
```

And i also changed the class name in html to "webicon facebook"